# What might make click events slow to fire?

Tags: javascript, onclick, mouseevent, jquery

For some reason, click events on my live server take significantly longer to fire than on my local development machine. For example, here's some basic code I used as a test:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[rel^="foxyLightbox"]').on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("HA!");
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I run that locally and click on links, the text prints out to the console pretty much instantaneously. If I click it a bunch of times in a row, there's no lag whatsoever.

When I run it on my live server, there's almost exactly a one second delay before the event fires. If I click it a bunch of times in a row, then there is lag and it prints out about once a second.

Here's a live example page: https://www.foxytronics.com/products/68-springrc-sm-s4303r-continuous-rotation-servo

The link that triggers the event is the large product image in the upper right.

At first I thought the issue was my javascript code, but then I commented it out and used the test code above (which is extremely short), so that can't be it. What could be delaying the click event from firing?

Comment: @C.S. My bad, the large picture. If you open your console and then click it, you'll see that there's about a one second delay between the click and the text printing out. Then if you click multiple times, there's a delay between each time it prints out.

Comment: When you test locally, did you test only the html file that uses that script, like having an html page with only the thumbnail and the js? or did you test it as it would appear on the website, completed, but just locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used chrome dev tools and I see that you have strange long mouseDown event handler:

[image: long mouse down event handler]

Some work is performed in JS script from static.getclicky.com

Comment: found same, 90% of time used by this.

Comment: Aha! So Clicky's the culprit! (Clicky is like Google Analytics, btw). I never thought to check the network requests, so thanks for your help and for showing me a new debug tool!

Comment: @Nate, Tony is using the Chrome Developer Tools Timeline JS Profiler, not checking network requests